# Upgrading From AngularJS to Angular 8 having problem with migrating from ng-include used inside ng-repeat

Tags: angular

Currently I am upgrading my application from Angular JS to Angular 8. I want to render multiple components using ngFor dynamically.

I have multiple UI Components and they are similar in nature. I want to iterate through and display the components. In Angular JS I can do 
this using ng-repeat along with ng-include based on template url passed from the data. This works well with AngularJS

But in Angular we do not have ng-include. So I was trying with switch case but in future new components can be added. So I want to make it dynamic based on the data.

## Angular JS

```
<li ng-repeat="component in ui.componentArray">
    <div ng-include="templateUrl" dynamicController="config.controller"></div>
</li>
```

The Component Array contains variable number of html component like Component1, Component2, Component3 etc with controller like ComponentController1, ComponentController3, ComponentController3 etc.

Angular 8 I tried using switch case but it is static. I want to make it dynamic as we can have more components.

## Angular 8

```
<div [ngSwitch]="component.name">
    <app-component1 *ngSwitchCase="'component1'"></app-component1>
    <app-component2 *ngSwitchCase="'component2'"></app-component2>
    <app-component3 *ngSwitchCase="'component3'"></app-component3>
</div>
```

How the above piece of code can be implemented in Angular 8.

Comment: Why not just *ngIf and control the value from ts code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need to load your components dynamically.

Angular 9 and prior

Put your components to be loaded dynamically in entry components

```
 entryComponents: [ App1Component, App2Component ],
```

Angular 10

```
 entryComponents is not required anymore
```

A host Component.

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HostDirective } from './host.directive';
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Output } from '@angular/core';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-host',
  template: `<ng-template cmp-host></ng-template>`
})
export class HostComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(HostDirective, { static: true }) host: HostDirective;
  @Input() public component: any;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }

  loadComponent() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);
    const viewContainerRef = this.host.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}
```

A directive to get the reference

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[cmp-host]',
})
export class HostDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

Use it like this

```
<app-host [component]='component1'></app-host>
<app-host [component]='component2'></app-host>
```

You may see a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5unoe)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this might be what you are looking for: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-ng-for-syntax

```
<!-- Angular -->
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    {{i}} {{item}}
  </li>
</ul>
```